# Can't find the longest occurancy in a set of duplicates

Tags: javascript, sequence, reduce, indexof

The target is to detect superstring in a set of arrays. In this case it should be 'bal' but I get 'lbal'.

```
  const arr = [
  ['g', 'l', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'l'],
  ['b','a','l','l']
  ]

const res = argv.reduce((acc, val) => acc.filter(elem => val.includes(elem)))
```

This function just gives ALL duplicates(items that are presented in any array) when I need only the most long duplicate sequence. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you want to find the global duplicates global? or per row?

Comment: @aleEspinosaM Global. One or a sequence (when it happens).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this person keeps editing his question to ask other things than he initially had.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I totally agree. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  const original = [
  ['a', 'b', 'm'],
  ['g', 'o', 'a', 'b'],
  ['w', 'o', 'u', 'k', 'a', 'b']
  ]
  
  
  // The easiest is to split up between unique results and duplicates
  let uniqueValues = []
  let duplicates = []
  
 // Now we're going to loop every array
 original.forEach((arr) => {
  // Loop every value inside the array
  arr.forEach((value) => {
    // Check if we had this value already
    if (!uniqueValues.includes(value)) {
      uniqueValues.push(value)
    } else {
      duplicates.push(value)
    }
  })
 })
 
console.log('Duplicates: ', duplicates)

// If you want remove the duplicates from the duplicates, use set

let uniqueDuplicates = [...new Set(duplicates)]

console.log('Unique duplicates: ', uniqueDuplicates)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create an object that counts how many times an element is present in the array of array

like this

```js
const arr = [
  ['a', 'b', 'm'],
  ['g', 'o', 'a', 'b'],
  ['w', 'o', 'u', 'k', 'a', 'b']
  ]

const countTimes = data => data.flat().reduce((res, v) => {
  
  return {
    ...res,
    [v]: (res[v] || 0 ) + 1
  }

}, {})


const duplicates = data => Object.entries(countTimes(data))
.filter(([v, n]) => n > 1)
.map(([v, n]) => v)

 console.log(countTimes(arr))
 console.log(duplicates(arr) )
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants? Unless you combine it with a filter where you check what is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to know in which array duplicates are, you can use [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get rid of nested arrays, then check simple array for duplicates.

```js
const arr = [
  ['a', 'b', 'm'],
  ['g', 'o', 'a', 'b'],
  ['w', 'o', 'u', 'k', 'a', 'b']
]

const arr2 = arr.flat() // ['a', 'b', 'm', 'g', 'o', 'a', 'b', 'w', 'o', 'u', 'k', 'a', 'b']

const hasDuplicates = new Set(arr2).size !== arr2.length
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a tally, to find how many each element globally is duplicated by doing a nested forEach

```
function findDuplicates(data) {
  const map = {};
  data.forEach((row) => {
    row.forEach((item) => {
      if (!map[item]) {
        map[item] = 1;
      } else [map[item]++];
    });
  });
  return map;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple counter object (if you know python, this is similar to `collections.Counter`):

```js
class Counter extends Map {
  update(values) {
    for (let val of values)
      this.set(val, 1 + (this.get(val) ?? 0))
  }
}

ARR = [
  ['a', 'b', 'm'],
  ['g', 'o', 'a', 'b'],
  ['w', 'o', 'u', 'k', 'a', 'b']
  ]

const tally = new Counter()

for (let subArray of ARR)
  tally.update(new Set(subArray))

for (let [element, count] of tally)
  if (count === ARR.length)
    console.log(element)
```

`count === yourArrayOfArrays.length` selects elements that appear in all arrays, you can replace it with `count > 1` to find any duplicates.

Comment: Why isn't 'o' a duplicate?

Comment: @Wimanicesir: there's no `o` in the first array